# pyinstaller issue with requests 'ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages.chardet.sys'

Tags: python-2.7, request, python-requests, importerror, pyinstaller

I have encountered this issue and tried all previous solutions to no avail. Have tried rolling back requests to older versions, have tried updating pyinstaller. Please guys, if you know a configuration that works, let me know.

I am compiling some python 2.7 code that uses Kivy

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot. I was piping the wrong python install. I use a separate version for other projects, and I sandbox my kivy one to prevent conflicts... too bad I forgot about that :)